# More than one function with keyup on Jquery?

Tags: jquery, keyup

I need to change the `ID` of an input text to use two functions of `keyup` with Jquery, for example I select the option number `1` and on my script I write a function keyup for id `1`and other for the number `2`, to know if it works I use `alert`, but always work the id put by default.

```js
$('#selector').change(function() {
  $('#1,#2').attr('id', $(this).val());
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#1').keyup(function() {
    alert("OPTION 1 SELECTED");
  });
  $('#2').keyup(function() {
    alert("OPTION 2 SELECTED");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<input id="1" type="text">
```

What wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding to the elements based on their original IDs. If you want the bindings to follow changing IDs you have to use event delegation.

```js
$('#selector').change(function() {
  $('#1,#2').attr('id', $(this).val());
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", '#1', function() {
    alert("OPTION 1 SELECTED");
  });
  $(document).on("keyup", '#2', function() {
    alert("OPTION 2 SELECTED");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<input id="1" type="text">
```

But this seems like a strange way to do this. Why not just use a single handler that does

```
alert("Option " + $("#selector").val() + " selected");
```

Comment: great it work perfectly!! Have a great day, you helped me!! ^ ^

Comment: @user13411530 do not use thanks, it worked etc. just mark the answer as answered or upvote the answer, or both

Comment: @BryanDellinger and you add a comment when neccessary, this web allow vote after x minutes of answered ; )

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selector').change(function() {

    $('#1,#2').attr('id', this.value);
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    alert("OPTION "+$(this).attr('id')+" SELECTED");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input id="1" type="text">
```